# QGIS best way for capturing features without geometry and child features

Tags: qgis-3, user-interface, relation, insert

I have two (PostGIS) layers in my QGIS (3.18) project and I defined a relation between them.
The first layer PARENT has no geometry.
The second layer CHILD is the child layer and has a geometry.
In the layer *form properties* of PARENT I made the relation visible, because I want to see all children in the attribute form of the PARENT as a list.

Now I want to capture a new PARENT with some CHILD features:

- switch PARENT to edit mode
- add record (Ctrl +)
- fill the form with PARENTs attributes and press OK.
- unfortunately the form is closed now. When I want to capture some CHILD features for my new PARENT I have have to search it in the attribute table - what is not so funny, when the PARENT layer has many features.

Is there a better way to it?

Maybe I can prevent the form from closing automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

- do not use *add record* from the toolbar in the main window
- open the attribute table and switch to form view
- use *add feature* and *save edits* in the attribute table
- the attribute table is not closed and the new record is still there
- adding CHILD features is now easy, because it is visible in the form.